# LINQ contains exactly matching

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

We have the following class structure and want to query all user who has at least all roles or more from the mustHaveRole Queryparameter. 
If someone has a good idea that would be cool :-)

```
public class User
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserRole> Roles { get; set; } = new HashSet<UserRole>();
}

public class UserRole
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; } = new HashSet<User>();
}

public class QueryHandler
{
    readonly List<User> Users = new List<User>();

    public IEnumerable<User> Handle(List<Guid> musthaveRoles)
    {
        var queryResult =
            from u in Users
            from r in u.Roles
            where musthaveRoles.Contains(r.RoleId) //ContainsAllExact and not has one of the roles???
            select u;

        return queryResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need an exact match you can use `SequenceEqual` method. To make it work you need to order your `ids`

```
public IEnumerable<User> Handle(List<Guid> musthaveRoles)
{
    var queryResult = Users.Where(
        u => u.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId).OrderBy(id => id)
            .SequenceEqual(musthaveRoles.OrderBy(id => id)));

    return queryResult;
}
```

This query will return only users who have exact same roles you expect and will filter out users who have more roles

---

EDIT:

> the users with more roles should be also in the queryResult

You can use `Intersect` method:

```
public IEnumerable<User> Handle(List<Guid> musthaveRoles)
{
    var queryResult = Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId)
      .Intersect(musthaveRoles).Count() == musthaveRoles.Count);
    return queryResult;
}
```

Check a [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6EyWGt)

Comment: cool, but the users with more roles should be also in the  queryResult

Comment: I extended the userobject with a collection of status. In the many to many relation they have a status value. my question is: how can we filter the users with the queried status and a minimum statusvalue. demo https://dotnetfiddle.net/CCVwEP

Comment: @Jorgenson it would be better if you create a new question for this. You can link this question with a new one or just copy example from net fiddle into new question

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
var queryResult = Users.Where(x => musthaveRoles.All(y => x.Roles.Select(z => z.RoleId).Contains(y)));

// or this way
var queryResult1 = Users.Where(x => !musthaveRoles.Except(x.Roles.Select(y => y.RoleId)).Any());
```